# Python3: Writing data of bytes in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write Bytes into a text file, but my problem is that I do not know how I can do this.
I tried to write bytes with the write() function into a text file but I got the error:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Comment: Show us your wanted string to be written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are hellbent on writing bytes to a textfile you could use `base64`. Any reader of the file would have to be aware of that.

```
import base64

b'\xff\x00'.decode()
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

base64.b64encode(b'\xff\x00').decode()
# '/wA='
base64.b64decode('/wA='.encode())
# b'\xff\x00'
```

if you want numbers one way would be to use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

by = b'\x00\xffhello'
' '.join(len(by) * ['{:d}']).format(*np.frombuffer(by, np.uint8))
# '0 255 104 101 108 108 111'
' '.join(len(by) * ['{:02x}']).format(*np.frombuffer(by, np.uint8))
# '00 ff 68 65 6c 6c 6f'
```

relevant docs: [`numpy.frombuffer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Comment: I want to write my binary data for example 0xFF into a text file, but I do not want to translate the byte into a letter. It should be a number in the text file.

Comment: @HunterxPokemon I've updated the answer; that more like what you want?

Comment: Do you know some references about this for example a documentation?

Comment: @HunterxPokemon I've added some.

Answer (score 2):

You need to open the file in binary mode, instead of text mode:

```
import io

with io.open('/tmp/thefile.dat', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(some_bytes)
```

Comment: But I want that the binary data is shown as a string in my file.

Comment: Sounds like you're confused and don't understand the difference between bytes and text.  There's really no such thing as a "text file" only bytes, and the bytes gets decoded to text.

Comment: So I can not write the bytes as the same numbers into a text file?
For example I read from a file bytes and I want that the bytes are in a text file as the same number.

Comment: You're still not making sense.  Files have bytes, end of story.  Whether those bytes represent text, numbers, or whatever depends on how you decode the file.  For anyone to answer your question completely, you will have to describe 1. what the data is in python and 2. how you want the data encoded in the file.

Comment: @wim C'mon be fair. At the abstraction level of, say, `open` there are text files and binary files, even though the precise object types may be `_io.whatever`

Comment: It's not unfair to request a clear enough problem description so that we don't have to guess at what's wanted here.  "A number in the text file" means what exactly, 0xff is 255 or "255" or...?

Answer (score -1):

For reference: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

```
with open('some.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(some_bytes)
```

Comment: OP uses Python3, change your link

Comment: How do you know that it is python 3?

Comment: This exception message could only be in Python3